# CryptopgraphicException When Trying to Unprotect Byte Array "the parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012, cryptography, windows-phone-8

Alright, I've been trying to encrypt and decrypt files for a while now and I keep getting this exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.

It writes the file perfectly, and the byte array does indeed have legal entries. But this is still thrown when I try to decrypt.

And here is the entire function:

```
    private static void loadTimes()
    {
        try
        {

            short[] encShorts = new short[bestTimes.Length / 2];

            IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store);

            StreamReader stmReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            int i = 0;
            while (!stmReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                encShorts[i] = short.Parse(stmReader.ReadLine());
                i++;
            }
            stmReader.Close();

            byte[] encBytes = new byte[bestTimes.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < encShorts.Length; j++)
            {
                encBytes[j * 2] = (byte)(encShorts[j] / 256);
                encBytes[j * 2 + 1] = (byte)(encShorts[j] % 256);
            }

            bestTimes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encBytes, null);

            checkForTimeAds();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Basically it is loading from a file to get the best time scores in the game, and since they are shorts I split them up into two bits each.

The following code throws the exception:

```
bestTimes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encBytes, null);
```

I've looked everywhere and it seems that a lot of people haven't gotten it resolved and some people say things about a "race condition" but I'm not entirely sure if that applies here. Why am I getting this exception?

The Saving code as requested by Jon Skeet:

```
    private static void saveTimes()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encResult = ProtectedData.Protect(bestTimes, null);

            short[] encShorts = new short[bestTimes.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < encShorts.Length; i++)
            {
                encShorts[i] = (short) (encResult[i] * 256 + encResult[i + 1]);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFile store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store);

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            foreach (short part in encShorts)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(part);
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't save the file.");
        }

        checkForTimeAds();
    }
```

Comment: Do you *really* have a file where each 16 bit value is stored as a string representation? That sounds like an awfully inefficient way of storing the data, aside from anything else.

Comment: You store always the incoming bytes in the same position. (Not incrementing i in the reading loop). But this is only the beginning.

Comment: @Jon Skeet-- Yes, it is irksome. I am currently trying to get this to work first before I optimize it. The different classes play with different types and to be quite honest it is irritating.

And Steve -- That is quite the embarrassing mistake on my part, I have fixed it now but still the same result (to be expected).

Comment: Can you show the first lines of your text file?. I am curious to see how are written these binary bytes that you are trying to read as they were some kind of text.

Comment: The file contains "256\n", which is then parsed to the byte array {1,0}

Comment: @Steve -- Heck even `byte[] test = { (byte)1, (byte)0 }; byte[] result = ProtectedData.Unprotect(test, null);` throws the same exception.

Comment: @JonathanPearl: Well I'd expect the protected data to be the *result* of some encryption - can you show that code?

Comment: @Jon Skeet -- Oh, yeah. I can do that. The question has been appended. (My apologies for the identity confusion)

Comment: It was @JonSkeet ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original conversion code (to a `short[]`) is broken:

```
short[] encShorts = new short[bestTimes.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < encShorts.Length; i++)
{
    encShorts[i] = (short) (encResult[i] * 256 + encResult[i + 1]);
}
```

That should be:

```
short[] encShorts = new short[encResult.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < encShorts.Length; i++)
{
    encShorts[i] = (short) (encResult[i * 2] * 256 + encResult[i * 2 + 1]);
}
```

Note the use of `encResult` instead of `bestTimes` when determining the length, and the doubling of `i` when accessing `encResult`.

Additionally, you haven't considered the last byte, if `encResult` has an odd number of bytes.

Fundamentally, it's not clear why you're converting a `byte[]` to a `short[]` and then writing it to disk as *text* in the first place. If you'd avoided all this conversion and just written the raw bytes out, you wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: I am stupid. Quite stupid. For some reason I thought the output of the save would have been the same size as the input... Didn't even think about salting and etc. This completely breaks my code of how to save and load. Now to BinaryWriter! I'll report back with results. Thank you so much, even if it doesn't work I'm sure you deserve an internet cookie or two just for your devotion -- quite the change since my last three or four questions here. EDIT: And it does! I can't thank you enough Jon, but thank you.

Comment: @JonathanPearl: You don't need `BinaryWriter`. Just use `stream.Write(encResult, 0, encResult.Length)`. When reading, don't forget that `Read` may not read all the data in one go - you should use the return value to observe how many bytes have been read, and read until it returns 0.

Comment: I guess these are the mistakes you really learn from. The BinaryWriter implementation works perfectly and is simple, would using the StreamWriter be any more efficient? And yes, I have removed all of the horrible, dreadful, painful, and erroneous conversions.

Comment: @JonathanPearl: No, `StreamWriter` would be *less* efficient - because it would require a conversion to text. `StreamWriter` is design to write text to a stream. You don't have text - you have binary data.

Comment: Yeah, I was going by a myriad of examples and trying to splice them together. I ended up with _that thing_ and we saw how that went. I'm glad it's all under control though (I didn't even know there was a Binary* class before asking the question nor did I ever think about looking for a class that had inherent byte[] writing capabilities -- stupid mistake on my part)